# How to update an added fabric.js shape as soon as it is resized?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am working on a Fabric Grid using Fabric.js and I want to add the dimensions of the shape that is added on the canvas. The new Width and Height is defined but I will need to not only show the dimensions on the screen, but also get it updated when I resize the shape.

Below is the JS function, where `newWidth` and `newHeight` are defined:

```
  function snapToGrid() {
    let checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
      //snap only to the grid
      const gridSize = 50;
      c.on("object:moving", function (options) {
        options.target.set({
          left: Math.round(options.target.left / gridSize) * gridSize,
          top: Math.round(options.target.top / gridSize) * gridSize,
        });
      });

      c.on("object:modified", function (options) {
        var newWidth =
          Math.round(options.target.getWidth() / gridSize) * gridSize;
        var newHeight =
          Math.round(options.target.getHeight() / gridSize) * gridSize;
        options.target.set({
          width: newWidth,
          height: newHeight,
          scaleX: 1,
          scaleY: 1,
        });
      });
    } else {
      c.off("object:modified");
      c.off("object:moving");
    }
  }
```

I am new to Fabric.js and would appreciate if someone helped me on this. Please let me know if I'' have to share more details of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I've answered my own question, so if anyone needs it, here's the below code that would help to dynamically show your shape's width and height while altered.

```
function onObjectScaled(e){
  var scaledObject = e.target;
  
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
      text.value = 'Width =  '+scaledObject.getWidth() + '   Height = '+scaledObject.getHeight(); 
}
```